# How do you implement this Wolfe Dual?

Tags: matlab, optimization, sum

1) Find the Wolfe Dual of this problem:

```
(NL) min sum(x_i*ln(x_i)), from i=1:n
     st. Ax <= b
```

2) Let A be a random 5x10 matrix, solve the Wolfe Dual using Matlabs fmincon, with 'interior point' as the algorithm.

---

Ok, so I found the Wolfe dual of the problem to be:

```
sup sum(x_i * ln(x_i)) + sum(y_j * (A_j * x - b_j))
    with x_i = e^(-1 - sum(y_j * A_ji))
    and i=1:n,   j=1:m
st. y >= 0
```

Now that the Wolfe Dual is in terms of only y, I think this can be done easily with anonymous functions. I am not a good enough matlab programmer to figure out how to implement this though. Any help here would mean the world to me. Thanks :)